# How can i reduce code ? discord bot python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have been making discord bot for me and my friends for some time.
I have already made a soundbar. It looks like this

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['A'])   
async def a(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice==None:
      channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
      await channel.connect()
    guild = ctx.guild
    voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=guild)
    audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('mp3//a.mp3')
    if not voice_client.is_playing():
        voice_client.play(audio_source, after=None)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)

    #2
@bot.command(aliases = ['q'])   
async def B(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice==None:
      channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
      await channel.connect()
    guild = ctx.guild
    voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=guild)
    audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('mp3//b.mp3')
    if not voice_client.is_playing():
        voice_client.play(audio_source, after=None)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
```

How can I get the same effect in shorter form? I mean, I dont want to reapeat the same part of code every time -

```
voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice==None:
      channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
etc.
etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

First, avoiding logic duplication is great. That's a really good thing to look for
Since your goal is to write better code, I assume the code you posted is for the sake of illustration, but just in case that's the way your code actually is, I suggest you avoid naming functions (or vars, or anything for that matter) with none explicit names. `a` is the worst you can name a function.

```py
async def play_sound(ctx, filename:str) -> None:
voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice==None:
      channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
      await channel.connect()
    guild = ctx.guild
    voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=guild)
    audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f'mp3//{filename}.mp3')
    if not voice_client.is_playing():
        voice_client.play(audio_source, after=None)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    
@bot.command(aliases = ['A'])   
async def a(ctx):
    await play_sound(ctx, 'a')
    


@bot.command(aliases = ['q'])   
async def B(ctx):
   await play_sound(ctx, 'b')
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you're right - names of my functions aren`t 'a' or 'b', I used this letters as example. As I said, its bot for my friends so when i'm writing the code, I'm using weird, iconic for our group names and I changed them in this post so they don't draw unnecessary attention.

Comment: This is really helpful if you really want to reduce the code. Appreciate your work dude!